# Determine whether the given function forms a subspace of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$\mathit{W} = \{ f\mid f(x)\,\mathrm{is\,integrable\,on\,interval\;[\mathit{ a, b}] \}} $$

How to determine whether this function forms a subspace of the vector space $F(-\infty,\;\infty)$? It would be appreciated if someone could provide an explanation to prove the same.

Comment: Just verify that this *set of functions* is closed under the vector operations: (pointwise) addition and multiplication by scalars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best if you first show your go at this question. Firstly, you need to remember what are the criteria for a set to be considered a subspace of a vector space:

1. Closed under addition.
2. Closed under multiplications.
3. Contains the zero vector.

Well, say $f(x),g(x)\in W, a\in\mathbb{F}$. We know $f(x),g(x)$ integrable $\to (f+g)(x)$ integrable. Therefore it is closed under addition. Moreover, $f(x)$ integrable $\to af(x)$ integrable, so it is closed under multiplication. Lastely, $f(x)=0$ is continuous and therefore integrable, meaning $\vec0\in W$. Therefore, $W$ is indeed a subspace of a vector space.